# security to consider in paypal call back php code

Tags: php, paypal

I am accepting payment with below html

```
<form name="myform" action = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method = "post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type = "hidden" name = "business" value = "test@ssssss.com">
<input type = "hidden" name = "item_name" value = "Update Plan">
<input type = "hidden" name = "loggedin_user_id" value="<?php echo $user->id;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="4.95">
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
<input name = "rm" value = "2" type = "hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" id="custom" value="{{ user_id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type = "hidden" name = "cancel_return" value = "http://website.com/">
<input type = "hidden" name = "return" value = "<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>pay">
<input name = "cbt" value = "Return to My Site" type = "hidden">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Upgrdate Now</button>
</form>
```

And in the php, I just update the user_role with 1, that means that the user has paid.

Is it secure enough? Can some one just post to my return URL and crack my payment system ? What security I should be adding in my php code ?

```
if(isset($_POST['loggedin_user_id']))
        {
            $this->user_model->set_user_attribute($_POST['loggedin_user_id'],'user_role',1);

        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This might be better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: I am just asking what security measures to be considered when accepting payments with paypal in your Call Back Code.

Comment: That's still too broad for this site. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT** assume that the user has completed a purchase just because they have visited your return URL. A user can read the return URL from your form and visit it manually. Additionally, in some cases, PayPal may hold a payment for verification; the user will be sent to the return URL, but the payment will not have gone through yet.

To determine whether a purchase has taken place, implement a PayPal [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) endpoint on your web site.

Comment: I understand, this is what i was talking about. From paypal site "PayPal sends a secure FORM POST containing payment information (IPN messages) to the URL. The IPN listener detects and processes IPN messages using the merchant backend processes.". In my case IPN Listener is the postback URL i believe and i want to know the security measures for the php page.

Comment: @formul1 The security measures are explained in their documentation on [Implementing an IPN Listener](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/). In short: your IPN listener posts the notification back to PayPal to confirm it is correct.

Comment: Will you consider my response back file AS ZERO Secure, where i am only checking if(isset($_POST['loggedin_user_id'])) ?

Comment: Yes, that's completely insecure. For one, it won't work. The return URL is visited with a GET request, not a POST. And even if you fixed that, a user could simply look at the form and visit the return URL without paying.

Comment: Thats why I am checking if $_POST is set on return url. If $_POST is not set the page wont execute. Even I am using same return url in the IPN PayPal Settings. so i believe IPN is calling the return url and then isset($_POST) is being checked. I still wonder why it is being considered as non secure

Comment: 1) IPN does not call the return URL. IPN calls the IPN endpoint you have configured for your account. 2) Using the return URL to check for purchases is insecure because anyone can determine what that URL is and visit it. They do not have to actually make a purchase to visit the return URL.